# How to transform an NSImageView in cocoa?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, animation

I'm struggling with cocoa. I'm trying to write this piece of animation from iOS into cocoa. The idea is to slightly decrease the size of the NSImageView and after the animation completes, increase it again to the original size. So that it looks as if the button (picture) was pressed.

```
@IBOutlet weak var vpnButton: NSImageView!

@objc func vpnButtonPressed(pressedGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: Constants.vpnButtonTapped)
        if (pressedGestureRecognizer.state == .began) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, animations: {() -> Void in
                self.vpnButton?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.965, y: 0.965)})
        } else if (pressedGestureRecognizer.state == .ended) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, animations: {() -> Void in
                self.vpnButton.isHighlighted = !self.vpnButton.isHighlighted
                self.vpnButton?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)})
        }
    }
```

In cocoa, I was able to find the clickGesture.  I'm not sure if this is the best choice.

So I came up with this:

```
@objc func vpnButtonPressed(clickedGestureRecognizer: NSGestureRecognizer) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: Constants.vpnButtonTapped)
        print("clicked")
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({_ in
            //Indicate the duration of the animation
            NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 0.5
            var transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.965, y: 0.965)
            self.vpnButton.layer?.setAffineTransform(transform)
        }, completionHandler:{
//            var transform = self.vpnButton.layer?.affineTransform()
//            transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
//            self.vpnButton.layer?.setAffineTransform(transform!)
            print("Animation completed")
        })
    }
```

This worked only once by moving the image slightly aside, but it doesn't make it smaller. If I uncomment the three lines in the completion handler, I don't see the animation moving it back either.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you need something like the following (sending action itself, if needed, is out of scope - here just animation)

[image: Cocoa custom NSImageView click animation]

```
class MyImageView: NSImageView {

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.wantsLayer = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.wantsLayer = true
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
          context.duration = 0.15
          self.layer?.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.965, y: 0.965))
        })
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
          context.duration = 0.15
          self.layer?.setAffineTransform(.identity)
        })
    }
}
```